# Qtcreator does not suggest available signals and slots in connect statement

Tags: qt

Using Qtcreator 4.8.2 and Qt 5.12.1 in archlinux/ubuntu, I'm trying to connect a signal to a slot using traditional method of QObject::connect, but when I open bracket after SIGNAL or SLOT macro, code completion does not suggest me available signals or slots. I haven't seen such a problem since I have updated Qt to this latest version. What's the problem?

example of the code:

```
connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(setEncValue()));
```

readyRead() and setEncValue() are not available in suggestion list, but not only these two slot and signal, there are actually no signals or slots shown in the suggestion list.

Comment: Why are you using the horrible old macros if you have Qt5?

Comment: @replete: Cuz they are not deprecated yet!

Comment: The Qt5 signals and slots give you compile-time checking, which is a big deal, and much more flexibility with what you can connect.

Comment: On further inspection, this seems to be a problem with the new Clang code model; it may be necessary to use an older version of the creator in the meantime. I'm using Qt 5.12 but 4.5 of the creator so I don't experience this problem.

Comment: Consider sending a bug report or a feature request off to Qt. This issue is unlikely going to be fixed by brute force...